# Exit VBA Main Subroutine from Called Subroutine

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, exit

I have a sub "main" which calls sub "prepare" as well as other subroutines.  I have an if statement in "prepare" that exits the sub if a condition is met.  However, it only exits that specific subroutine and then goes on to execute all of the other subroutines in "main".

```
    If oAltIDLocationDictionary.Exists(sAltID) Then
        MsgBox "It appears that there are two duplicate ID's in your alternate ID list.  Duplicate ID's cannot be processed, please consolidate the location information into a single ID or remove the duplicate ID from the Alt-ID list."
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Is there a way to exit the "main" from the "prepare" sub it's calling so that when the condition is met in the "prepare" sub the "main" sub stops and no further code is executed?

Comment: You could use `End`.

Comment: That worked!  It didn't work a minute ago, I was getting an error that the if statement wasn't ended properly, but it worked just now.

Comment: Thanks!  If you put that as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: "It didn't work a minute ago" - you probably tried replacing `Exit Sub` with `End Sub`.  `End` is an executable statement that ends program execution.  `End Sub` is a code "marker" (best description I can think of) that simply tells the compiler where the end of a procedure is.  (But, I guess, an `End Sub` has an implicit `Exit Sub` built into it, so it isn't *just* a "marker".)

Comment: I'd just like to take the opportunity to highlight the use of functions. If your Sub was a function, you could get it to return a specific value on exiting - then the rest of the code in `Main` or whatever can behave differently. It's a good concept to get hold of and it seems you're at a stage where it may be learned and come in handy one day...

Comment: @jamheadart agreed. `End` is essentially a Big Red Button that nukes the entire runtime context (i.e. resets any global state back to defaults). I've never **needed** to use `End` even *once* - the proper answer is *proper control flow*, not a Big Red Button.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info - I'll take it into consideration as I proceed with Excel VBA!

Comment: @Mat'sMug Aww - the Big Red Button is a **good** thing - I **like** the fact that it clears all global variables, etc, because a lot of other things nuke them too, so it keeps me in the habit of ensuring any global variables are reset whenever starting the macros again.  Otherwise I spend hours scratching my head (no, not because of lice!) trying to work out why the code works some times and not at other times.

Comment: @YowE3K ah, but that's when you *have* global variables ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cease execution of your macro immediately, without returning to the calling procedure, you can use the `End` statement.

Comment: As @mats-mug pointed out in his comment on the original question, using `End` is like a big red button that nukes everything, and clears any state that your code has developed..

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the subs into functions, and if the functions return a certain value, the main sub will then exit.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim bTest As Boolean

    ' blah blah

    bTest = Prepare
    If bTest Then Exit Sub

    ' blah blah

End Sub

Function Prepare() As Boolean

    Prepare = False

    If oAltIDLocationDictionary.Exists(sAltID) Then
        MsgBox "It appears that there are two duplicate ID's in your alternate ID list."
        Prepare = True
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```